# Eclipse (Nvidia NSight 7.0) C++ chrono autocomplete

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, nsight, c++-chrono

I am using the chrono library in a project and would like to enable autocomplete in eclipse. I've searched the internet, but failed to find a way to do so.

The IDE doesn't autocomplete std::chrono, neither system_clock.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Igor Campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following settings I made it partly work. Autocomplete works but only after manually adding the includes:`#include <chrono>` (same for other c++11 stuff like `shared_ptr`).

You need to manually activate c++11 in the indexer. For nsight 7.0 you need to do the following steps:

In the project properties go to:

1. **General** -> **Path and Symbols** -> **Symbols** -> **Add...** -> Add the `__cplusplus` variable with the value `201103L` (c++11). The default value will be overridden.
2. **General** -> **Preprocessor and Include Paths, Macro etc.** -> **Providers** -> Activate **CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings** -> Decative **Share setting entries between projects (global provider)** -> To **Command to get compiler specs:** add `-std=c++11` to the line.
3. Apply changes and rebuild the index if not done automatically (right click on project -> **Index** -> **Rebuild**).

The problem to solve is how to force the indexer to work even when the header is not included...